# How do I open a VS Code editor on local machine instead of remote when using VSC as git editor?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine

**Setup**

- Local machine - Windows 11, VSCode version 1.85.1
- Remote machine - Windows 11 Virtual machine, VSCode version 1.85.0
- VSC is set as the default git editor, difftool, and mergetool
- Running git commands from VSC integrated terminal using command prompt

**Issue Description**

When I run a git command that opens an editor, I expect a VSC editor to open on my local machine. This doesn't work and the terminal window keeps waiting, so I interrupt it using Ctrl+C. While debugging I found that if a VSCode window is open on the remote machine (GUI connected via RDP), the expected git editor opens on the remote machine. If no VSC window is open on the remote machine, then a new one does **not** open but I see 9 new background processes started in the Task Manager.

How do I change this behavior to open the git editor on the local machine?

**VSC integrated terminal output**

```
user@remote-machine C:\path\to\git\repo>git config --global --edit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...<User input Ctrl+C> error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
```

**Global .gitconfig file on the local machine**

```
[core]
    editor = code --wait
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --reuse-window --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --merge $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED
```

**List of relevant extensions on local machine**

- ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
- ms-vscode.remote-explorer
- ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh

**Global .gitconfig file on the remote machine**

```
[core]
    editor = code --wait
    autocrlf = false
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --reuse-window --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --merge $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED
```

**List of relevant extensions on remote machine**

- ms-vscode.remote-explorer
- ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
- ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9605/550426. but I'm still not sure how to expand that into a full solution.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791800/1978365